# Only accept input within a range

Tags: python

I want the code not to take the input when it is more than 23 or less than 0. 
It does reject negative values but still values bigger than 23.

```
height=int(input("select height: "))


while height<0 and height>23:
        print("please give input between 1 and 22")


for i in range(height):
    print(" "*(height-i)+"#"*(i+1))
```

I googled some stuff and kinda try to understand with trial and error but I couldn't.

```
 for i in range(height):
    print(" "*(height-i)+"#"*(i+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The current code checks for if `height` is *simultaneously* less than 0 and greater than 23. Instead, try:

```py
while height < 0 or height > 23:
  height = int(input("input height: "))#using input as well, to get new working value
```

As for how the last lines work: they create an ASCII pyramid of "#"s with equal height and width.

- the first line `for i in range(height)` is just for how many rows there are.
- the second line

  - prints empty spaces  - `" "*(height-i)`: for example if it is the 1st row of a 6 height pyramid, will print 5 spaces; if it is the 2nd row, will print 4 spaces. The multiplication just prints that character *x* times.
  - prints "#"s - `"#"*(i+1)`. This works just like the above, but comes after the spaces, and in inverse.

Comment: Good answer and explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
while height<0 and height>23:
        print("please give input between 1 and 22")
```

You should be using if instead of while

```
for i in range(height):
    print(" "*(height-i)+"#"*(i+1))
```

The first line describes how many times the loop will execute 
Second how many times the string will be printed in each line.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while height <= 0 or height >= 23:
    print("please give input between 1 and 22")
    height = int(input("select height: "))
```

while works when the value is true, and the number is simultaneously less than 0 and more than 23 cannot to be, use 'or' not 'and'